# Передать значение input обработчику

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

У меня есть `input` на странице в котором по умолчанию `value` задано 1.
При клике на кнопку я передаю значение через ajax, значение этого поля должно передаться обработчику. В обработчике прописано

```
$amount_units = $_POST['amount_units'];
```

но `$amount_units = null`

Как правильно записать в `data`?
Вот моё поле и код js

```js
function AjaxCountTotalPriceProduct(amount, total_price_product, total_price_products) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://practice//CountTotalPriceProduct',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      "amount_units=": amount.value,
      "total_price_product": total_price_product,
      "total_price_products": total_price_products
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      $('#amount').val(response[0]);
      document.getElementById(total_price_product).innerHTML = response[1];
      document.getElementById(total_price_products).innerHTML = response[2];
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="col-4 p-0">
  <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="amount" aria-describedby="emailHelp" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'').substr(0,2)" disabled value="1">
</div>

<div class="col-3 p-0 text-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Увеличить" onclick="AjaxCountTotalPriceProduct('amount', 'total_price_product', 'total_price_products')">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Что за аргумент `amount` в функции? Что туда передается? `data` это стандартный джаваскрипт объект, название поля объекта просто `"amount_units"`, без `=`. Можно даже и без кавычек.

Comment: Исправил ошибку, написал amount_units.
Всё равно не работает.
Как правильно прописать вот здесь  {"amount_units=" : amount.value

Comment: Приведите код __вызова__ функции `AjaxCount...`

Answer (score 1):

Я не очень понимаю зачем вы используете `onclick` если у вас уже есть jquery и можно просто навесить обработчик через `on`, но ладно, это ваше дело. Вернемся к вызову функции `AjaxCountTotalPriceProduct`.

Вы передаете туда 3 аргумента, каждый из которых **строка**:

```
AjaxCountTotalPriceProduct('amount', 'total_price_product', 'total_price_products')
```

Аргумент `amount` со значением `'amount'` - это просто строка. У строки нет никакого свойства `value`, поэтому `amount.value` не возвращает ничего. Откройте консоль разработчика в браузере и проверьте на наличие ошибок.

Какой вывод - надо передавать либо значение поля. Значение поля обычно берется через функцию `val()`. Таким образом, вызов функции можно записать как:

```
AjaxCountTotalPriceProduct(
    $('#amount').val(),        // выбираем `#amount`, берем его значение
    'total_price_product', 
    'total_price_products'
);
```

Либо можно по прежнему передавать строку `'amount'` и в самой функции уже получать значение поля:

```
function AjaxCountTotalPriceProduct(amount, total_price_product, total_price_products) {
    $.ajax({
        url:  'http://practice//CountTotalPriceProduct',
        type: "POST",
        data: {"amount_units" : $('#' + amount).val(), "total_price_product" : total_price_product, "total_price_products" : total_price_products},
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#amount').val(response[0]);
            document.getElementById(total_price_product).innerHTML = response[1];
            document.getElementById(total_price_products).innerHTML = response[2];
        }
    });
}
```

Обратите внимание, что ключи объекта `data` содержат только нужное вам название, никаких `=`.

Также **почаще** дебагайте свой код, для вывода значений в консоль используйте `console.log`/`console.dir`.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо.
А что вы писали по поводу 'on'  ?

Вместо onclick писать on ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addToCartAjax(message) {
  var myProductFilt = document.getElementById('productFilt').value;
  var mySelQuantity = document.getElementById('inpAvNum').value;
  var myFilterGroup = document.getElementById('filterGroup').value;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.$_SESSION['USER_LANGUAGE'].'/cart/addAjax/';?>",
    data: {
      productCode: '<?php echo $productByCode[0]['
      code ']; ?>',
      productFilt: myProductFilt,
      selQuantity: mySelQuantity,
      filterGroup: myFilterGroup
    },
    success: function(jsondata) {
      var jstotal = JSON.parse(jsondata);

      document.getElementById('topCartPrice').innerHTML = jstotal.totalPrice;
      document.getElementById('topCartPriceItem').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('topCartQuantity').innerHTML = jstotal.totalQuantity;
      document.getElementById('topCartQuantityItem').style.display = 'block';
      //    console.log(jstotal.totalPrice);

      swal(message, {
        icon: "success",
        buttons: false,
        timer: 1700
      });
    }
  });

  return false;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="toch-button toch-add-cart" name="cartAdd" id="cartAdd" onclick="addToCartAjax('<?php echo product_added_to_cart; ?>');"><?php echo product_button_add_to_cart; ?></button>
```

Вот Вам пример реализации.